# LINQ query performance issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ expression in method syntax

```
IEnumerable<PageElement> elements_test = ObjectContext.PageElements
            .Where(_dateDebutCheck).Where(_dateFinCheck)
            .Where(pe => _activeLanguageCheck(pe, language))
            .Where(pe => _typeCheck(pe, typeElement))
IList<PageElement> list = elements_test.ToList();

private readonly Func<PageElement, bool> _dateDebutCheck = pe => pe.DateDebut.HasValue && pe.DateDebut.Value <= DateTime.Now;
private readonly Func<PageElement, bool> _dateFinCheck = pe => !pe.DateFin.HasValue || pe.DateFin.Value > DateTime.Now;
private readonly Func<PageElement, byte, bool> _activeLanguageCheck = (pe, l) => pe.PageElementLanguages.Where(y => y.Active).Select(y => y.LanguageId).Contains(l);
private readonly Func<PageElement, byte?, bool> _typeCheck = (pe, t) => pe.TypeId == t;
```

I am finding that when the call to ToList is taking quite a while and am wondering if there is anything that I am doing wrong that is causing the performance drop.  I am only running the ToList at this point as a test but it is taking several seconds to return on only about 7000 records.  How can I improve this?

Comment: You are aware that by using `Func<T, bool>` you are automatically using the LINQ To Objects extensions instead of LINQ To SQL? EF uses `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, which means you're effectively doing all filtering client-side...

Comment: I would run SQL Profiler and see what SQL is being generated, it should be relatively simple to read, then take it from there. If it's not doing any filtering on the database side like Patryk suggests, then it should be easy to test and fix

Answer (score 9):

It is slow, because you are no longer doing the querying in database, but in memory. It pulls all data from `PageElements` table and then filters it in memory. The reason for this is that you are using `Func<>` delegates, which forces LINQ to use `Enumerable` instead of `Queryable`. To fix this use `Expression<Func<>>` instead.

But I would recommend against trying to compose your queries the way you are doing it. It makes queries harder to read and fine-tune. Especially if you expect some kind of SQL to come out of it.

Maybe you could do it through extension methods :

```
// needs to be in static class
public static IQueryable<PageElement> TypeCheck(this IQueryable<PageElement> q, byte? typeElement){
    return q.Where(pe=>pe.TypeID == t); // also this might not work is typeElement is null
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
ObjectContext.PageElement.TypeCheck(typeElement).ToList(); // etc..
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I use the Expression<Func<>> in the Where calls?

Comment: @jimmyjambles I'm sure it would be hard to do the way you composed your query. Put everything together and it should work properly. Try searching LINQ and compose. You might get some ideas how to do it correctly.

Comment: There are many places in my code where I am using different combinations of the different predicates, I only used 4 in this example but I often am calling quite a few more, I would like to keep them all at the same place, I am able to use Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>> works for the first 2 predicates but can't seem to get the syntax right for the predicates that require parameters

Comment: @jimmyjambles Only thing I can recommend : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linq+compose

Comment: @Euphoric, could you please take a look at this one to see what is wrong there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807879/net-linq-expressionfunct-bool-performance-issues