# .NET LINQ Expression<Func<T, bool>> Performance Issues

Tags: performance, linq, express, lambda

I have two functions as follow -

```
public IQueryable<RequestSummaryDTO> GetProgramOfficerUSA(Guid officerId)
{
    List<string> officerCountries = UnityProvider.Instance.Get<IProgramOfficerService>().GetPOCountries(officerId).Select(c => c.CNTR_ID.ToUpper()).ToList();
    Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> countriesFilter = (a) => officerCountries.Contains(a.tblTaskDetail.FirstOrDefault().tblOrganization.ORG_Country.ToUpper());

    Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> USAAndNotDelegated = LinqUtils.And(this.USAFilter(), this.NotDelegatedFilter(officerId));
    Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> countriesOrOwned = LinqUtils.Or(countriesFilter, this.OwnedFilter(officerId));
    Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> filter = LinqUtils.And(USAAndNotDelegated, countriesOrOwned);

    return this.Get(filter, TaskRequestState.USA);
}



private IQueryable<RequestSummaryDTO> Get(Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> additionalFilter, TaskRequestState? TaskRequestState = null)
{
   var Tasks = this.TaskRequestRepository.List(additionalFilter).Where(x => x.tblTaskDetail.FirstOrDefault().PD_TaskRequestID == x.Id && 
            (x.tblRequestDetail.AD_Status == (int)RequestStatus.Paid || x.tblRequestDetail.AD_Status == (int)RequestStatus.NotConfirmed));

    if (TaskRequestState == TaskRequestState.USA)
    {
        Tasks = Tasks.Where(w => (w.tblTaskDetail.FirstOrDefault().PD_PStatus == null || w.tblTaskDetail.FirstOrDefault().PD_PStatus == 125));
    }
    else
    {
        Tasks = Tasks.Where(w => w.State == null);
    }

    return Tasks.ToList().Select(TaskSummaryFactory.CreateDto).AsQueryable();
}
```

I used Expression> and IQueryable in the LINQ.  It is supposed to use LINQ To SQL instead of LINQ To Objects.  The performance should be good.

But I do not see that.  I believe the LINQ pulls every table's data into memory to process using LINQ To Objects.  I do not see a join sql query sent to SQL Server tracking by SQL profile but a bunch of individual table selection statement.

It takes over 10 minutes to get something return from

```
return Tasks.ToList().Select(TaskSummaryFactory.CreateDto).AsQueryable();
```

I know the problem is in

```
Expression<Func<TaskRequest, bool>> countriesFilter = (a) => officerCountries.Contains(a.tblTaskDetail.FirstOrDefault().tblOrganization.ORG_Country.ToUpper());
```

tblTaskDetail is a big table.  If I switch to a smaller one, the performance is noticeably improved.

Anyone can help find out why is wrong there.

Thanks,

Update 1 -
The statement from Entity Framework logged in SQL Profile are all like this -

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT   [Extent1].[ORG_ID] AS [ORG_ID],  [Extent1].[ORG_CreatedBy] AS [ORG_CreatedBy],   [Extent1].[ORG_CreatedOn] AS [ORG_CreatedOn] FROM [dbo].[tblOrganization] AS [Extent1]  WHERE [Extent1].[ORG_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 uniqueidentifier',@EntityKeyValue1='E8C3F120-AA40-445E-A8A0-2937F330D347'

They are all just having individual table select statement, not joined sql statement.

Update 2 -

I was wrong in Update 1.  I missed the join SQL statement.  The problem is that the generated SQL is too poor.  There are 6 nested select statements, 11 LEFT OUTER JOINs, and 10 OUTER APPLYs.  The query is too long and can not post here.  Executing the generated SQL takes 9 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried logging what SQL is being sent to the server?

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet good to see you again.  I updated the question with more info you are interested in.

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you try rewriting this as direct LINQ query? My opinion is that the query is simply too complex to be converted directly into SQL. Especially for LING to SQL, which is known for not doing good job at interpreting LINQ. For example, the two first lines in GetProgramOfficerUSA are something that is hard to express in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded the EF STE 5 to EF6.  Now the performance is better.  The page loading time is cut down to 1.5 minutes from 12 minutes.